# Windows 10 not showing in Grub menu

Tags: windows

I Installed Ubuntu Desktop on Windows 10.

Now the grub menu is not showing windows 10 in boot menu.

Grub repair gave me the following link.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KtNZsBYgf8/

Kindly help me to recover back the Windows 10.

Regards
Jayamohan.M

Comment: It looks like you erased the Windows boot partition which has bootmgr & BCD. You can run Windows repairs on your sda2 partition, but must move boot flag to sda2. Grub does not use boot flag. But Windows must have boot flag on its bootable partition or to run repairs on it. Only a Windows repair disk or installer with repair console can add back the Windows missing files, it cannot be fixed from Ubuntu.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392/  then you will need to restore grub to MBR: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the GRUB configuration file by running `sudo update-grub` on a terminal. (Remember to type in your password. It does not show on the screen for security.) That should create a new GRUB configuration drive with Windows 10 included.

If that didn't fix your problem, install GRUB Customizer by following the instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) and check if `os-prober` is on. If it is not, turn it on by going to the "General Settings" page and checking the "Search for other operating systems" checkbox. Then, try running `sudo update-grub` again.

Feel free to contact me if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

I tried with sudo update-grub. 
It's NOT fixing the priblem.

I installed GRUB customizer by running below comments.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Later checked for os-prober.
This gave error as:
unshare failed: Operation not permitted.

Also i could not find 
"Search for other operating systems" checkbox..under settings
Please guide me on this.

Thanks n Regards
Jayamohan.M

Comment: @mohan The ISO you probably used to install Ubuntu is probably corrupted. Try to download it again, check the MD5 checksum by following the instructions on the Ubuntu page and try to install it again. Hope this fixes your issue.